# Does CVE-2019-0211 affect Apache w/ php-fpm?

Tags: php, apache

> **Intro**
>
> From version 2.4.17 (Oct 9, 2015) to version 2.4.38 (Apr 1, 2019),
>   Apache HTTP suffers from a local root privilege escalation
>   vulnerability due to an out-of-bounds array access leading to an
>   arbitrary function call. The vulnerability is triggered when Apache
>   gracefully restarts (apache2ctl graceful). In standard Linux
>   configurations, the logrotate utility runs this command once a day, at
>   6:25AM, in order to reset log file handles.

https://cfreal.github.io/carpe-diem-cve-2019-0211-apache-local-root.html

Does that mean Apache w/ php-fpm is not vulnerable?